# How to fix issue with appending optgroup to a select2 drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a drop down using `selct2` all in JQuery. So I have an ajax call that is sent from Java to my Jquery that has a list of parent and child elements and it is being held in a List as Strings. So for example:

```
WEB
-->Apache
-->Nginx
-->Random

DATABASE
-->Sql
-->NoSQL

COMPUTER SYSTEM
-->Windows File Share
```

I am looking for any way to fill a select2 dropdown by making a `<optgroup>` and having values inside of that group. I looked into making a HashMap or another way, but not sure how to go about it in JQuery. Please help. Below is the code I got so far but, it is only adding everything as a `option`, instead of surrounding it in `optgroup`.

**Code:**

```
$.each(result, function(i, obj) {

                                    var div_data = "<option value=" + obj + ">"
                                            + obj + "</option>";
                                $(div_data).appendTo('#selectData2');
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyms54qa/1/) that assumes you're receiving a JavaScript object that is structured like my example:

```
// Example javascript object where the option group title is the key/index
// and the options for each are an array
var example_object = {
'Web': ['apache','nginx','random'],
'Database': ['sql','nosql'],
'Computer System': ['Windows','Other']
};

// The element you're appending options to
var select = $('select');

// Loop through each item in the object
$.each(example_object, function(category,items){

  // Create an optgroup element with jQuery, the label is the category
    var group = $('<optgroup>').attr({label: category});

  // Loop through items in that category
  $.each(items, function(index,item){

    // Create an option element with jQuery, set the value and html
    // Append to the group
    $('<option>').attr({value: item}).html(item).appendTo(group);

  })

  // Now we have an optgroup containing all of the children items
  // Append to select element
  group.appendTo(select);

})
```

This isn't perfect but I hope it helps!